# Throttle based on a previous Observable

Tags: rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have the following setup, which, every 3 seconds would make a new HTTP request to a server.

```js
  getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
    return timer(0, 3000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.http.get(param1))
    );
  }
```

If a given request takes more than 3 seconds, the `switchMap()` (I think) will cancel it and fire off a new one.

Now, I want to make it so that if a request is taking more than 3 seconds it waits for it to complete before firing off another one. Just for context, the idea is that if there's performance issues with the requests, my front-end is not stuck firing off and cancelling requests too early.

I somewhat got this to work with the following:

```js
currentObs: Observable<any>;

getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, 3000).pipe(
    throttle(_ => this.currentObs),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.currentObs = this.http.get(param1)
      return this.currentObs;
    })
  );
}
```

This will keep track of the `currentObs` which is the observable of the current HTTP request. It then passes it to a `throttle()` method so that the values from `timer()` that normally prompt new requests are ignored until the request (`currentObs`) completes.

This seems to work but it's a bit awkward as I'd need to keep some of the state outside the `pipe()`. It's also a bit confusing because the throttling is based on an event that happens after it. I've been looking for a way to pass the result of the `switchMap()` onto the `throttle()` but first I didn't find one, and second, wouldn't that cause the `throttle()` to be in the wrong side of the pipe?

Is there a neater way to achieve this using RxJS?

## Edit:

With @Mrk Sef's answer for a more elegant solution and @kvetis' warning for handling errors, I ended up with the following pipe that will make a request, wait for 3 seconds after a success and then make another request. If the request fails, it's going to wait for 3 seconds and make another request. and then start from the top.

```js
getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(param1).pipe(
    repeatWhen(s => s.pipe(
      delay(3000)
    )),
    retryWhen(s => s.pipe(
      delay(3000)
    ))
  );
}
```

Comment: Your simplest solution is to use your first implementation and switch out your `switchMap` for `exhaustMap`. The downside here is that if your calls start taking 3.1s to complete, then you only end up calling the server every 5.9s instead of every 3 seconds. That sort of the worst-case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ExhaustMap

Try to run `this.http.get` every 3 seconds, if the previous call isn't done within 3 seconds, do nothing and try again 3 seconds later.

```js
getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, 3000).pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.http.get(param1))
  );
}
```

#### Repeat with Delay

Whenever the previous call ends, wait 3 seconds and then make the call again

```js
getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(param1).pipe(
    repeatWhen(s => s.pipe(
      delay(3000)
    ))
  );
}
```

#### Comparative Repeat

Repeat the call every 3 seconds, unless the call takes longer than 3 seconds in which case repeat the call as soon as the previous call ends.

This is closest to what you described. It works by using a silent timer to artificially "extend" the HTTP call. This works because `merge` won't complete until both inner observables complete. This means the fastest the merge will complete is 3 seconds.

```js
getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return merge(
    this.http.get(param1),
    timer(3000).pipe(
      filter(_ => false)
    )
  ).pipe(
    repeatWhen(s => s)
  );
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions! From what I gather, in this context, they all behave the same. I went with the second one (`repeathWhen()`) as it seemed the clearest in terms of what it is doing.

I also wanted to mention that with both `repeathWhen()` and `exhaustMap()` the source observable needs to be completed. I had an obscure bug where a http interceptor was leaving my request observable without completion so your suggestions didn't work at first.

Comment: Yes, all three solutions require `http.get` to complete since that's the trigger to either `repeat` or finish `exhaust`ing. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is a very elegant solution there is. You could get your hands more dirty stepping outside the world of observables and keeping the state outside in a simple callback are whatever. But I would say you solved the issue correctly.

Only be careful, that if the request fails, then the whole timer fails. You need to
recover in both `switchMap` and `currentObs`, if you want to continue with next request even if the previous fails. Since `throttle` needs to receive a value for the pipe to continue, you should not just recover to `EMTPY`. Let's emit null.

```
getData(param1: string): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, 3000).pipe(
    throttle(_ => this.currentObs),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.currentObs = this.http.get(param1).pipe(
          catchError(e => {
              console.error(e);
              return of(null); // so the throttle continues with next value
      return this.currentObs;
    }),
    filter(identity) // use identity from RxJS so we filter out the null
  );
}
```

Generally speaking, what you're trying to achieve is called **backpressure**. You can google "RxJS backpressure" and come up with different techniques. In most of them, you cannot achieve what you want without having an external Observable to feed info back to the source Observable.

Comment: good insight about what happens if the requests fails. Already had problems with `EMPTY` so nice to see an alternative to it!

Comment: I must admit that as per @MrkSef answer this basically implements ExhaustMap and that should be the accepted answer. :-)